# save images on s3 and saving corresponding object on mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, amazon-s3

I am wondering what is the correct way of uploading an image to S3 and saving the image document in mongodb.

the logic I've implemented so far is this:

- user uploads an image through a form (nodejs)
- the image file is saved to S3
- at the same time I generate an image document that also has the image url uploaded to S3

All works well, but I want to be able to use the objectID of the mongodb doc to name the image then uploaded to S3.

So how can I get the objectID of the mongoDB image doc so then I can use the objectid to name the image, something linke:  03scc8399n39n.png

The problem is that until I save the image doc in mongodb I don't have the objectId so then does that mean that I have to do something like:
- save an image document in mongodb
- find it
- get the unique objectId by fetching the doc just saved on mango and reading its id
- use the id to name the image
- update the image doc with the url of the image just uploaded to S3

The issue with this is that I have to save, find-update, save the doc in mongodb, instead of just creating the object and saving it to mongodb... I think I'm not approaching this in the best way due to my inexperience.

What is the better way of storing images on S3, tracking them in mongodb and using the doc id as the name of the image?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually do have the _id value before you save the document. The way all drivers work is that they well add a newly created ObjectID instance and assign it to the "_id" field of your document before the save is executed. In other words, if you provide an _id value for the document you're saving the save command is actually an update, and if you don't it's simply an insert with a newly created ObjectID instance.

As such, all you have to do is either (pseudo):

```
myImageDoc = new ImageDoc();
imageId = new ObjectID();

myImageDoc._id = imageId;
db.images.save(myImageDoc);

myPng = imageId + ".png";
```

or (since most drivers extend the document instance with the _id value set) :

```
myImageDoc = new ImageDoc();

db.images.save(myImageDoc);
imageId = myImageDoc._id;

myPng = imageId + ".png";
```

I'm not a JavaScript expert so you'll have to translate that to that language as appropriate.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I save the image object with mongoose using .save() then like you explained the _id field now has the id mongodb assigned to the object so then I can use it for naming the image.